# Android Studio 4 без вызова clean project компилирует старый код

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Если я вношу изменения в кодовую базу проекта, то Run 'app' компилирует мне старую версию, словно ничего не менялось, пока я не вызову clean project или rebuild project. Если изменения вносятся в layouts, то они видны. Отключать instant run в AS4 негде, добавление "Gradle-aware Make" в "Run/Debug configuration" ничего не даёт.

Интересно, что если создать новый проект, то в нём такой проблемы не будет.